# Expanding a macro as many times as possible without error

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3, latex3, mapping

I'd like compute cosets using the `permute` package.

Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,permute}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Create a new command to compute the right coset Hg, taking in the element and the set
%% Clear a local clist for use
%% For each element in the set (#2)
%%% Set the current permutation to the identity
%%% Set the current permutation to the one we are looking at in the iteration
%%% Compose it with the element we were given in #1 on the right
%% Type the clist; Print the clist
\NewDocumentCommand \PMTCosetR { m m } {
  \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } {
    \pmtid          \pmtdo{##1}      \pmtdo{#1}  % compressed to avoid scrollbar on TeX.SX
    \clist_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_clist \pmtprint
  }
  \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
  \ensuremath{\Big\{\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {,}\Big\}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\PMTCosetR{(12)}{(),(123),(132)} \par
Expecting values:
\begin{itemize}
\item \pmt{(12)()}
\item \pmt{(12)(123)}
\item \pmt{(12)(132)}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The critical problem is actually what is being put into the list:

```
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\pmt@GetPrintArgs {\pmt@PrintPmt \pmt@curr }}
>  {\pmt@GetPrintArgs {\pmt@PrintPmt \pmt@curr }}
>  {\pmt@GetPrintArgs {\pmt@PrintPmt \pmt@curr }}.
```

Unfortunately, changing the appropriate argspec (`V|o`→`x`) results in an error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\pmt@GetPrintArgs #1->\let \pmt@order 
                                      \pmtprintorder \def \pmt@next {#1}\@if...
l.27 \PMTCosetR{(12)}{(),(123),(132)}
```

I figure there must be a way to control how many times `\pmtprint` is expanded, since one expansion is obviously not cutting it.  Can I expand it exactly twice?  Three times?  As many times 'as necessary', whatever *that* means?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the 'bigger picture' aim is here. The `\pmtprint` command isn't expandable, so you can't get the 'results' and store them.

Comment: It's not only a question of expansions: note that the error happens at `\let`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compute the composition, so why trying to do it when building the `clist` to deliver?

I use a sequence, because it's more efficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,permute}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \PMTCosetR { m m }
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \pmt{#1##1} } }
  \bigl\{\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,}\bigr\}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\PMTCosetR{(12)}{(),(123),(132)}$

Expecting values:
\begin{itemize}
\item \pmt{(12)()}
\item \pmt{(12)(123)}
\item \pmt{(12)(132)}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I read the question, I thought you would provide a new expl3-package ;-)